# How to zip a directory without having to cd into the directory and still keeping the nested folder structure

Tags: zip

As part of a sh script I create a folder I would like to zip. Looking something like this:

```
my-directory-to-zip
├── file1
├── file2
├── dir1
│   ├── file3
│   ├── file4
```

When I then zip it the files are then nested inside my-directory-to-zip, where I sould like he folder structure to look something like this inside the zip file:

```
file1
file2
dir1
├── file3
├── file4
```

you can imagine my current sh-script looks something like this:

```
<commands that makes and fills my-directory-to-zip>
zip -r my-zip-file.zip ./my-directory-to-zip
rm -r my-directory-to-zip
```

I have tried:

```
<commands that makes and fills my-directory-to-zip>
cd my-directory-to-zip
zip -r ../my-zip-file.zip .
cd ..
rm -r my-directory-to-zip
```

but that fails with:

```
bash: cd: my-directory-to-zip: No such file or directory
```

When I copy pastes the commands directly into the terminal it works perfectly, with the cd into the directory.

Comment: is the `-` infront of your my-directory-to-zip a typo here in the post or is it part of the filename?

Comment: Typo meant rm -r my-directory-to-zip

Comment: are you running the script exactly outside of my-directory-to-zip?

Comment: yes I run it exactly outside. The directory does not exist before (and I also delete it after the process)

Comment: are you changing any ownership of the directory, or the user that runs the script is different? I really cannot see anything going wrong with your code. if you delete all test files/directories created by your script, and run the script again, without the `rm`, when the script ends is the `directory` and `directory.zip` there?